# Magento2 - How to create a backend module to insert data into a table?

Tags: magento2, module, database

I want a module to insert data into a custom table, created a custom table also created a menu in the admin menu now how can I add details to the table from the `admin -> menu -> module name`. also, I want to display the details in the admin side and also delete and edit function.

Comment: follow one of the core modules. I recommend Magento_Cms. It's the simplest. Try to replicate it using your own entity name and fields

Comment: can you help me out

Comment: Please Refer this link to perform backend CRUD.
https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/create-admin-grid-magento-2.html

Comment: i followed the step but  its not working